# Ps4 controller won’t connect

Tags: ps4, controllers

My two original controllers no longer connected to my ps4 so I set out and bought a brand new controller, in which then that controller will not connect to the console either. It will only flash for a few seconds then return to orange, I have searched numerous forums for answers and none have worked, I have also callled PlayStation but they said only my two older controllers could be damaged but doesn’t explain the new controller problem, please help.

Answer (score 0):

It might sound obvious but have you tried connecting it to your PS4 and holding down the share and PS button at the same time?

Comment: there is also a reset button beside the top right-hand screw on the back of the controller that might help.

Comment: If you want to add to your answer, use the edit button.